# Тарантул не поднимается после перезапуска (invalid instance UUID)

Tags: tarantool

Настройки box.cfg

```
box.cfg {
    listen = config.tarantool.port;
    --background = true;
    work_dir = dirLog;
    io_collect_interval = nil;
    net_msg_max = 1024;
    readahead = 16320;
    memtx_memory = 4096 * 1024 * 1024; -- 4GB
    memtx_min_tuple_size = 16;
    memtx_max_tuple_size = 1 * 1024 * 1024; -- 1Mb
    vinyl_memory = 128 * 1024 * 1024; -- 128Mb
    vinyl_cache = 128 * 1024 * 1024; -- 128Mb
    wal_mode = "write";
    wal_max_size = 256 * 1024 * 1024;
    checkpoint_interval = 60 * 60; -- one hour
    checkpoint_count = 6;
    snap_io_rate_limit = nil;
    force_recovery = true;
    log_level = 6;
    too_long_threshold = 0.5;
    --log = '| cronolog tarantool.log';
    pid_file = dirLog .. 'tarantool.pid';
    log_format = "json";
    feedback_enabled = false;
    worker_pool_threads = 5;
    too_long_threshold = 0.05;
}
```

Логи после перезапуска

```
{"time": "2020-09-08T06:37:25.473+0600", "level": "ERROR", "message": "XlogError", "error": "\/var\/lib\/tarantool\/00000000000000000000.xlog: invalid instance UUID", "pid": 1 , "cord_name": "main", "fiber_id": 102, "fiber_name": "tarantool-entrypoint.lua", "file": "\/usr\/src\/tarantool\/src\/box\/xlog.c", "line": 461}
{"time": "2020-09-08T06:37:25.473+0600", "level": "FATAL", "message": "can't initialize storage: \/var\/lib\/tarantool\/00000000000000000000.xlog: invalid instance UUID", "pid": 1 , "cord_name": "main", "fiber_id": 102, "fiber_name": "tarantool-entrypoint.lua", "file": "\/usr\/src\/tarantool\/src\/box\/box.cc", "line": 2193}
```

Answer (score 0):

Видно, что pid:1, значит тарантул запускается в докере.
В этом случае между перезапусками, проверьте что примонтированные директории указывают в те же что и были места.

В этом случае выглядит так, что снапшот от одного запуска, а xlog от другого.